# AWS Cron.yaml enable flag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, worker

I have two AWS environments that i am using for worker tiers. I would love to be able to deploy the same code set to both of them.  however I am looking for a way to include a enable flag into the software configuration at the environment level so that only 1 of them actually loads the cron.yaml for periodical tasks.

has anyone ever been involved with something like this and if so how?

Thanks

Comment: Rather than trying to sabotage cron.yaml, can you ignore the scheduled requests based on an environment variable?

Comment: Thats what I am trying to do. however I am not able to figure out a way to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might do this as follows:

1. Use the same `cron.yaml` for both ElasticBeanstalk Worker-Tier Environments.
2. Set up an OS/Process environment variable separately for each ElasticBeanstalk Worker-Tier Environment that specifies which type of worker tasks it should accept.  You can set these in the ElasticBeanstalk console under Configuration > Software Configuration > Environment Properties.

[image]

3. In your code, check the environment variable while responding to the scheduled events configured by cron.yaml.

Checking the environment variables is language-dependent, it would look something like this in Node.js, for example:

```
if (process.env["WORKER_TYPE"] == "TypeA") {
    // Do stuff
}

if (process.env["WORKER_TYPE"] == "TypeB") {
    // Do other stuff
}
```